# How long does it take to access stack memory?

Tags: c, performance, memory, time

Does re-declaring the same variable over and over again affect the performance of the code?

```
int i,a;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
// Some operations with a
}
```

**V/S**

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
int a;
// Some operations with a
}
```

Comment: incorrect assumptions all over. Due to [as-if rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule) there need not be any difference.

Comment: Aren't local variables destroyed at the end of their scope?

Comment: It is likely that storage for `int a;` in the second example is allocated once only for each call of the function anyway. Defining it within the `for` loop restricts the  access to it that the compiler will allow (its scope), even though it physically exists outside of the code block.

Comment: So does it call the stack for each iteration?

Comment: I read it somewhere on SO that by limiting the scope of a variable, one can ensure that more memory is available to the stack memory?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "call the stack."

Comment: It more usually done that way to restrict the scope of `a` than to save on stack space.

Comment: So these minor things don't reduce the performance of the code?

Comment: Let the compiler deal with that: don't worry about micro-optimisations.

Comment: So can't I help the compiler help with those micro-optimization :(?

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow no you can't. The scope does not ensure that the variable is *destroyed* at the end. Did you read the Q/A I linked to?! All programs that have the same external behaviour can be compiled to the same code. If you have got *2* programs with *different behaviour* it is different then...

Comment: Does unwanted declaration increase the compile time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally "stack variables", what are really local variables, are zero-cost. The only price you'd pay is if there's initialization of some sort.

The compiler may or may not reserve memory for that value. In the second case you don't actually use `a` so it will probably be eliminated by the optimization pass, making it truly zero cost.

Don't think of them in terms of "stack". That's an antiquated concept that pre-dates optimizing compilers.

Comment: So declaring a variable in the block of a loop doesn't affect the performance as local variables destroyed at the end of their scope?

Comment: Look at the assembly output to be sure.

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: Each compiler has a different method, but they can all do it.

Comment: For Turbo C compiler?

Comment: Maybe, but that compiler is museum grade. Why not Visual Studio Express?